# Deploying Elasticsearch on ecs fargate - HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, docker, elasticsearch

I am trying to deploy elasticsearch on AWS ECS fargate service. I have successfully deployed a version of elasticsearch with flag `discovery.type=single-node` and that works fine without any issue, but this has certain memory limitations and I cannot use it for prod.

Next step I got rid of the flag `discovery.type=single-node` set the following env variable via the task definition on AWS console `ES_HEAP_SIZE=10g` of the heap size. Also I have assigned `8GB` of memory to the task and the same to the container and `2vCPUs`.

I am getting few errors:

- `HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError`

```
{"type": "server", "timestamp": "2022-05-01T14:10:45,376Z", "level": "INFO", "component": "o.e.n.Node", "cluster.name": "docker-cluster", "node.name": "ip-172-31-10-153.eu-central-1.compute.internal", "message": "JVM arguments [-Xshare:auto, -Des.networkaddress.cache.ttl=60, -Des.networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=10, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -Xss1m, -Djava.awt.headless=true, -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8, -Djna.nosys=true, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages, -Dio.netty.noUnsafe=true, -Dio.netty.noKeySetOptimization=true, -Dio.netty.recycler.maxCapacityPerThread=0, -Dio.netty.allocator.numDirectArenas=0, -Dlog4j.shutdownHookEnabled=false, -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true, -Djava.locale.providers=SPI,COMPAT, --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED, -XX:+UseG1GC, -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp/elasticsearch-18437358607495407146, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -XX:HeapDumpPath=data, -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log, -Xlog:gc*,gc+age=trace,safepoint:file=logs/gc.log:utctime,pid,tags:filecount=32,filesize=64m, -Des.cgroups.hierarchy.override=/, -Xms4096m, -Xmx4096m, -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=2147483648, -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=4m, -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30, -XX:G1ReservePercent=15, -Des.path.home=/usr/share/elasticsearch, -Des.path.conf=/usr/share/elasticsearch/config, -Des.distribution.flavor=default, -Des.distribution.type=docker, -Des.bundled_jdk=true]" }
```

- `max file descriptors [4096] for elasticsearch process is too low, increase to at least [65535]`
- `max virtual memory areas vm.max_map_count [65530] is too low, increase to at least [262144]`

I tried different approaches like `nofile=65535:65535`, `memlock` but didn't work for me.

Comment: Does this answer https://www.devopsschool.com/blog/elastic-search-error-max-file-descriptors-4096-for-elasticsearch-process-is-too-low-increase-to-at-least-65535/#:~:text=Elastic%20Search%20Error%20%E2%80%93%20max%20file,increase%20to%20at%20least%20%5B65535%5D&text=To%20set%20ulimit%20value%20on%20a%20parameter%20use%20the%20below%20command.&text=Persistent%20limits%20can%20be%20set,conf%20file.

Comment: @SergioSantiago not really :(

Answer (score 1):

**vm.max_map_count**

AWS ECS Fargate does not let you change the vm.max_map_count value. If you want to stick with the Fargate you can add the following value in your elasticsearch.yml file. But this might have some performance degradation.

```
node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

Another approach might be switching to ECS EC2. With in this scheme you can update the vm.max_map_count value.

**ulimits**

For the ulimits you should update this in your added container at the task definition. Select nofile and set the soft limit and hard limit with the value 65536.

[image]